# Having problems getting values from foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

trying to get id from each person

```
$person = $request->input('person'); 
//values for person: Murdock,Wayne
$values = explode(',' , $person);

if(count($values) > 1) {
    //count($values) = 2
    foreach($values as $val) {
        $get_id = Tag::where('name', $val)->get();

        foreach($get_id as $get) {
            echo "id=".$get->id;
            $result= FileTags::with('file')->where('tag_id', $get->id)->get(); 
        }
    }
 }
```

when i do `echo $get->id` just getting id=1, when is supossed to be id=1 and id=2

Murdock -- id:1

Wayne   -- id:2

```
|table filetags|
|  id  | tag_id | file_id |
|  1   |   1    |    2    |
|  2   |   1    |    3    |
|  3   |   2    |    4    |
|  4   |   3    |    1    |

$result = FileTags::with('file')->where('tag_id', $id->id)->get();
```

I should get files with id 2,3 and 4

Model TAG

```
public function fileTag() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\FileTags');
}
```

Model Archive

```
protected $table = 'files';

public function fileTag() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\FileTags');
}
```

Model FileTags

```
public function tag() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag' , 'tag_id');
}

public function file() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Archive', 'file_id');
}
```

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**

```
 |table tag|
    | id  |   name    |
    |  1  |  Murdock  |
    |  2  |  Wayne    |
```

Result from echo $obt_id;

```
 [{"id":1,"name":"Murdock","description":"Description","type":"0","status":"1","created_at":"2016-07-20 18:01:14","updated_at":"2016-07-20 18:01:14"}][]
```

from var_dump($obt_id)

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(App\Tag)[267]
      protected 'table' => string 'tags' (length=4)
      protected 'fillable' => 
        array (size=4)
          ...
      protected 'connection' => null
      protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
      protected 'keyType' => string 'int' (length=3)
      protected 'perPage' => int 15
      public 'incrementing' => boolean true
      public 'timestamps' => boolean true
      protected 'attributes' => 
        array (size=7)
          ...
          ...
          ...

C:\wamp64\www\Petro\app\Http\Controllers\CatalogedController.php:53:
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[272]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=0)
```

Comment: You're overwriting `$result` in every execution of the loop.

Comment: can you give me an idea how to work it?

Comment: First thing - correct this line `if(count(values) > 1) {` to `if(count($values) > 1) {`. The second thing - can you show us rows in `Tag` table?

Comment: Can you show us the result of this code `var_dump($val, $get_id);` placed just after the line `$get_id = Tag::where('name', $val)->get();`?

Comment: You can `var_dump($values)` to check if it contains the data you are expecting. Same with other variables.

Comment: @jaysingkar Yes, I'm getting the data from $values when i do `echo "values= " .$val;`  - Murdock and Wayne

Comment: @Elio what about  `$get_id` ? did you check if you r getting the values both times ?

Comment: @jaysingkar  Probably he meant `$get_id`. A Common Typo. There is, anyways, no `$obt_id` in the code ;-)

Comment: You've show us the echo form Murdoc. Can you show us the echo for Wayne also?

Comment: @jaysingkar      Excuse me... really ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a Variable, `$result`; initialize it as an Empty `Array`and then simply push all the Results of evaluating the code: `FileTags::with('file')->where('tag_id', $get->id)->get()` into that the `$result` Array. And, in the end, Check if the `$result` Array is not empty. If it's not, you may simply implode it using  comma (Assuming it is a String) and echo your Results...

```
<?php

    $person = $request->input('person');
    //values for person: Murdock,Wayne
    $values = explode(',' , $person);
    $result = array();    // <== INITIALIZE TO AN EMPTY ARRAY... 

    if(count($values) > 1) {        //<== $values NOT values...
        //count(values) = 2
        foreach($values as trim($val)) { //<== TRY TRIMMING OFF WHITE SPACES. 
            $get_id = Tag::where('name', $val)->get();
            foreach($get_id as $get) {
                echo "id=".$get->id;
                // PUSH THE DATA INTO THE ARRAY...
                $result[] = FileTags::with('file')->where('tag_id', $get->id)->get();
            }
        }
    }

    // CHECK IF $result IS NOT EMPTY 
    if(!empty($result)){
        // CONVERT THE ARRAY TO A STRING (ASSUMING ITS CONTENT ARE NOT OBJECTS OR ARRAYS)
        $result = implode(", ", $result);

        // ECHO OUR YOUR RESULT...
        echo $result;
    }
```

Comment: You are focus on `$result` and you are right but the problem is not there becasue the line setting `$result` doesn't change any of this variables: `$values`, `$val`, `$get_id` and `$get`. The problem is the line `echo "id=".$get->id;` always return `id=1`. You are right that there should be `count($values)` but it was probably a mistake with copy/pase because `count(values) > 1` returns `false` and rise a warning so the code inside this `if` will never run.

Comment: Well that was my bad guys it should be `if (count($values)>1)`  but the real problem is `echo "id=".$get->id;` still getting  id=1

Comment: `echo "id={$id }";` Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id then when i try this `$id = $obt_id[0]->id;` getting the `id=1` but the result Undefined offset: 0

Comment: @Elio    Within the first `foreach` Loop; After the assignment to `$get_id`; Try to `var_dump($get_id);` and post back here what you get, please....

Comment: @Elio  Cheers, mate & Good Luck... ;-)